# How do I abstract a task when using polymorphism?

Tags: php, polymorphism

I've read numerous SO posts about Polymorphism, and also the other really good one at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-and-applying-polymorphism-in-php/ Good stuff!

---EDIT---
Inside of the PDFFormatter class, I had to use (instanceof) in order to figure out if some code should be included in the returned data because I was hard coding the individual field names inside the formatter. How can I abstract that responsibility? ***I AM ASSUMING THIS IS NOT THE BEST WAY***

I am also trying to pass in different kinds of profiles to be formatted. Note also that there can be many formatter types. Thanks sooooooo much in advance! Please PHP only! thanks!

File 1. FormatterInterface.php

```
interface FormatterInterface
{
    public function format(Profile $Profile);
}
```

File 2. PDFFormatter.php

```
class PDFFormatter implements FormatterInterface
{
    public function format(Profile $Profile)
    {
        $format = "PDF Format<br /><br />";
        $format .= "This is a profile formatted as a PDF.<br />";
        $format .= 'Name: ' . $Profile->name . '<br />';

        if ($Profile instanceof StudentProfile) {
            $format .= "Graduation Date: " . $Profile->graduationDate . "<br />";
        }

        $format .= "<br />End of PDF file";
        return $format;
    }
}
```

File 3. Profile.php

```
class Profile
{
    public $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function format(FormatterInterface $Formatter)
    {
        return $Formatter->format($this);
    }
}
```

File 4. StudentProfile.php

```
class StudentProfile extends Profile
{
    public $graduationDate;

    public function __construct($name, $graduationDate)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->graduationDate = $graduationDate;
    }
}
```

File 5. index.php

```
//Assuming all files are included......

    $StudentProfile = new StudentProfile('Michael Conner', 55, 'Unknown, FL', 'Graduate', '1975', 'Business Management');

    $Profile = new Profile('Brandy Smith', 44, 'Houston, TX');

    $PDFFormatter = new PDFFormatter();
    echo '<hr />';
    echo $StudentProfile->format($PDFFormatter);
    echo '<hr />';
    echo $Profile->format($PDFFormatter);
```

Comment: Please check the wording of your question. There is no need to get into ecstasy just by posting a question and leaving exclamation marks all over the place. Also please make your question more concrete, in my eyes it's not really clear what you ask about. Or perhaps the punctuation is hiding it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answers and comments! I haven't had a chance to look through them in detail yet. I was going to put "not sure how to ask this question" in the title, but I thought it might not be a good idea. I will really try to think about the exact question I am asking and change the title. Thx @hakre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make Profile an abstract class and define a mechanism to get properties from it, no matter what 'kind' of profile it is.

Profile class might have a method to get the properties (already set, maybe while constructing it), perhaps using [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). Thus, any object that extends Profile has already a mechanism to 'format' itself depending on the set properties.

I hope it helps and made myself clear.

## UPDATE:

Here's the code I came up with when I try to achieve the kind of behavior I think you are trying to achieve.

First, lets define an interface for the formatter:

```
/**
 * Formatter interface
 *
 * @category  Formatter
 * @package   Formatter
 * @author    Saul Martinez <saul@sharkwebintelligence.com>
 * @copyright 2012 Shark Web Intelligence
 * @license   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Apache License, Version 2.0
 * @version   1.0
 * @link      http://www.sharkwebintelligence.com
 */
interface IFormatter
{
    /**
     * Object formatting.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function format();
}
```

Nothing special, though. Now lets define a kind of helper to hold the fields or properties for, in this case, a profile:

```
/**
 * Profile field.
 *
 * @category   Formatter
 * @package    Profile
 * @subpackage Field
 * @author     Saul Martinez <saul@sharkwebintelligence.com>
 * @copyright  2012 Shark Web Intelligence
 * @license    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Apache License, Version 2.0
 * @version    1.0
 * @link       http://www.sharkwebintelligence.com
 */
class ProfileField
{
    /**
     * @var string $name Field name.
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @var mixed $value Field value.
     */
    public $value;

    /**
     * Factory method to create a profile field.
     *
     * @param string $name  Field name.
     * @param mixed  $value Field value.
     *
     * @return ProfileField
     */
    public static function factory($name, $value)
    {
        $field = new self();
        $field->name = $name;
        $field->value = $value;
        return $field;
    }

    /**
     * Format the profile field.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name . ': ' . $this->value . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The next class, the `Profile` class, I tried to make it a little flexible:

```
/**
 * Profile.
 *
 * @category  Formatter
 * @package   Profile
 * @author    Saul Martinez <saul@sharkwebintelligence.com>
 * @copyright 2012 Shark Web Intelligence
 * @license   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Apache License, Version 2.0
 * @version   1.0
 * @link      http://www.sharkwebintelligence.com
 */
abstract class Profile implements IFormatter
{
    /**
     * @var array $fields Profile fields.
     */
    public $fields;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * - Set options.
     *
     * @param array $options Profile options.
     */
    public function __construct($options)
    {
        if (is_array($options)) {
            $this->setOptions($options);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Format implementation.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function format()
    {
        $output = '';
        foreach ($this->getFields() as $field) {
            $output .= $field;
        }
        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a field to the fields list.
     *
     * @param ProfileField $field Field to add.
     *
     * @return Profile Provides a fluent interface.
     */
    public function addField(ProfileField $field)
    {
        $this->fields[] = $field;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set profile fields.
     *
     * @param array $fields Profile fields.
     *
     * @return Profile Provides a fluent interface.
     */
    public function setFields(array $fields)
    {
        $this->fields = $fields;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get profile fields.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFields()
    {
        return $this->fields;
    }

    /**
     * Set profile options.
     *
     * @param array $options Profile options.
     *
     * @return Profile Provides a fluent interface.
     */
    public function setOptions(array $options)
    {
        $methods = get_class_methods($this);
        foreach ($options as $name => $value) {
            $method = 'set' . ucfirst($name);
            if (in_array($method, $methods)) {
                $this->$method($value);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And finally, the student profile class, which could override any of the `Profile` class methods if you want to add an specific behavior:

```
/**
 * Student profile.
 *
 * @category   Formatter
 * @package    Profile
 * @subpackage Student
 * @author     Saul Martinez <saul@sharkwebintelligence.com>
 * @copyright  2012 Shark Web Intelligence
 * @license    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Apache License, Version 2.0
 * @version    1.0
 * @link       http://www.sharkwebintelligence.com
 */
class StudentProfile extends Profile
{
}
```

Now, you just need to instantiate `StudentProfile` class and add some fields to it:

```
$studentProfile = new StudentProfile(
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            ProfileField::factory('Name', 'Buddy'),
            ProfileField::factory('Birth date', '1983/05/05'),
            ProfileField::factory('Graduation date', '2000/01/01'),
        ),
    )
);
echo $studentProfile->format();
```

Hope it helps and I made my self clear.

## UPDATE:

I just wanted to add that when implementing OOP in any language, one thing I think it's very important to bear in mind is the [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) principle.

It might feel 'natural' to add features and behaviors while you are abstracting your classes, but it's not a good idea to add them only because 'you think' you might need them in the feature. So, think twice whether a method or feature needs to be added and when.

Comment: @Hernan Velasquez, wouldn't it be better to iterate the object properties and format them in that `formatSpecific` method?

Comment: Hey Saul, I'm not sure what you mean by define a mechanism to get properties from it? Are you refering to what Herman did by defining formatSpecific() ? Could you make a code example?

Comment: I'm sorry about being so vague in my posts. I just made a set of classes to clarify what I understand you want to achieve.

Comment: Wow, how long did it take you to put that together? That is perfect for helping me understand how to do things I never knew how to do!!! +1 for the incredible detail and clarity!

Comment: It just took me about five minutes, but this is an approach I've been using for a long time. I'm glad that helped you!

Comment: Do you by any chance have any links to any small/medium projects that you have worked on that I can read through and study the code? I'm trying to learn as much as I can and after seeing your update, I know I can learn a tremendous amount from your code!) Small examples like that are awesome learning tools!!!!!!

Comment: I've been trying to build a set of tools here https://github.com/samacs/sharkframework, using the http://framework.zend.com. Reading the ZF code has really helped me a lot on understanding some patterns. It's just a tool, once you know the basics, try to stick to one, there are a lot of frameworks worth checking.

Comment: Thx Saul!!! I will download it and take a look!! Yeah, I want to look through and understand all of the ZendFramework 2 code, but after downloading and starting to try to figure out how it all is put together, it got really complex really quick!! Especially the server manager! So it is going to take a lot of time to really dissect it and see how it works! But I agree completely!!!! Thx again!!!! I hope your answer helps others learn too!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18200/discussion-between-darga33-and-saul-martinez)

Answer (score 1):

I should do the following:

Make profile abstract and define and abstract method formatSpecific()

```
    abstract class Profile {

        abstract protected function formatSpecific();
        ...
    }
```

In the class Student:

```
    protected function formatSpecific() {
        $format .= "Graduation Date: " . $this->graduationDate . "<br />";
    }
```

And in the format function of the class PDFFormatter:

```
public function format(Profile $Profile)
{
    $format = "PDF Format<br /><br />";
    $format .= "This is a profile formatted as a PDF.<br />";
    $format .= 'Name: ' . $Profile->name . '<br />';

    $format .= $Profile->formatSpecific();
    $format .= "<br />End of PDF file";
    return $format;
}
```

In that way, you get rid of the instanceOf conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `Late Static binding`

Your format function can be changed to static,

```
public static function format($profileData)
{
    $format = "PDF Format<br /><br />";
    $format .= "This is a profile formatted as a PDF.<br />";
    $format .= 'Name: ' . $profileData['name'] . '<br />';

    $format .= static::getProfileSpecificFormat($profileData['date'] );

    $format .= "<br />End of PDF file";
    return $format;
}
```

And profile class must be like this,

```
class Profile
{

    public static function format($profileData)
    {
        return PDFFormatter::format($profileData);
    }

    public static function getProfileSpecificFormat($date)
    {
        return "Graduation Date: $date<br />";
    }

}
```

Later if you have 10 more kinds of Profiles, you can easily call the PDF format function using profile list as an augment.

Comment: but in OOP don't we want to try to steer away from static methods? Aren't static methods just procedural code but stored within a class definition? I'm trying to learn the best way to go about doing things. That's why I ask.

Comment: Static methods are not procedural code, But it behave same for all the objects... In your example PDF is generic class. It is not related to any of your profile classes. We use static method to have independent methods.. Once you call the function you don't need to worry what it does ... you don't need to match your calling object with called class functions ..